# Get list of only users where all related records are marked as complete

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a problem to get all user complete lists from database

Assume, I have table like this

```
user table
------------------------
| id|name|
------------------------
|1  |sandi
|2  |caca
|3  |andi



(User has many) complete_example table
------------------------
| user_id|is_complete|
------------------------
|   2    |false
|   2    |true
|   1    |true
|   1    |true 
|   1    |true
|   2    |true
|   3    |true
|   3    |true
|   3    |true
```

how to get all user who all is_complete column is true, using eloquent laravel ?

I hope my question was clear

The results what I want like this

```
------------------------
| id|name|
------------------------
|1  |sandi

|3  |andi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need users whose all associations in related table `complete_example` are true, So there are 2 ways to get the desired users, In plain SQL the query will be like

Using a correlated query for user table to exclude users who have any record in `complete_example` with `is_complete = 0`

```
select *
from user u
where not exists (
  select 1
  from complete_example
  where u.id = user_id
  and is_complete = 0
);
```

If you have already setup your relations between your models then in query builder this can be achieved as

```
$users = User::whereDoesntHave('complete', function (Builder $query) {
                $query->where(is_complete,0);
            })->has('complete')
              ->get();
```

In above snippet you can remove `->has('complete')` If you don't want to specify that each user should have atleast one association.

Another way is to user aggregated query that will join all the related records and will then match the total count of user  associations with conditional count where `is_complete = 1`, if these 2 count values match with each other this means all associations are true for particular user

```
select u.id,
       u.name
from user u
join complete_example c on u.id = c.user_id
group by u.id,
         u.name
having count(*) = sum(case when c.is_complete = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
```

Representation in query builder will be like

```
$users = DB::table('user as u')
           ->join('complete_example as c', 'u.id', '=', 'c.user_id')
           ->groupBy(['u.id','u.name'])
           ->select(['u.id','u.name'])
           ->havingRaw('count(*) = sum(case when c.is_complete = 1 then 1 else 0 end)')
           ->get();
```

Sample data to test queries

```
CREATE TABLE complete_example
    (`user_id` int, `is_complete` int(11))
;
    
INSERT INTO complete_example
    (`user_id`, `is_complete`)
VALUES
    (2, 0),
    (2, 1),
    (1, 1),
    (1, 1),
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (3, 1)
;


CREATE TABLE user
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(5))
;
    
INSERT INTO user
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'sandi'),
    (2, 'caca'),
    (3, 'andi')
;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cb3c1/4)

Comment: Thank for your answer, I will to try after back to home and tell you if get a success or errors, appreciate

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple [join](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins) will do it:

```
 $values = DB::table('users')->join('complete_example', 'complete_example.user_id', 'users.id')
            ->where('is_complete', '=', true)->get();
```

Comment: I need all is complete is true, if I run query like that, I got user with is complete false

Comment: of course not , you will get users with is_complete true only! otherwise, what the point from the where in query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereHas` clause to query the relationships.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Something like

```
$users = User::whereHas('complete', function ($query) {
    $query->where('is_complete', true);
});
```

Comment: I need all is complete is true, if I run query like that, I got user with is complete false too